# How to .filter and .reduce javascript array object

Tags: javascript, arrays, methods, web-deployment

WebDev Student. I am having an issue with using `.filter + .reduce` array methods and chaining to return the total cost of both items. Codeburst.io on the subject is super helpful but I need direction on how to apply to this specific exercise as I am targeting a property: value in the array.

This is an exercise in reducing the amount of code., so rather than using a `for` loop to iterate through an array, I need to apply a method(s) to .filter through and .reduce to return the total cost of each item in the array.  `.price`

> Using the `shopCart` variable, create a function that takes the `shopCart` variable and returns the total cost of both items as the `total` variable. Add Code after "// code below".

```js
var shopCart = [
  {
    id: 0,
    name: 'Womens Shirt',
    price: 30,
    size: 'Small'
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'childs shirt',
    price: 12,
    size: 'Large'
  }
]

function getCost(items){
  let total = 0;
  // code below

  // code above
 return total;
}

getCost(shopCart) < --- Add

let cost = getCost(shopCart); < ---OMIT

console.log(cost); < -- OMIT
```

PLease re-review - Code has been amended.

Comment: what is the expected output?42?

Comment: I guess you're supposed to use `map+reduce` for this, not `filter+reduce`.

Comment: You only need to use `Array.reduce`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here’s a more explicit approach.

```
function sum(nums) {
  return nums.reduce((a, b) => a + b)
}

const prices = items.map(item => item.price)
const total = sum(prices)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using iteration – for example, a for loop. In the `getCost` function, we have a total variable with an initial value of zero. Then for each element in the items array, the price is used to accumulate the total. However, this functionality is similarly available using the [reduce method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

```js
var shopCart = [
  { id: 0, name: 'Womens Shirt', price: 30, size: 'Small' },
  { id: 1, name: 'childs shirt', price: 12, size: 'Large' }
];

function getCost(items) {
  var total = 0;
  items.forEach(e => total += e.price);
  return total;
}

let cost = getCost(shopCart); // 42
let costWithReduce = shopCart.reduce((a, c) => a + c.price, 0); // 42

console.log(cost, costWithReduce);
```

Comment: Hey Callam, would it be a bother to get a brief breakdown of the code you added?

I've been struggling with the concept of how methods are applied to an array, specifically where data is stored and how the function is applied.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array#reduce`. In a `total` accumulator, you can add `price` of each object.

```js
var shopCart = [{id: 0,name: 'Womens Shirt',price: 30,size: 'Small'},{id: 1,name: 'childs shirt',price: 12,size: 'Large'}];

function getCost(items){
 return items.reduce(function(total, obj){
  return total + obj.price;
 }, 0);
}

let cost = getCost(shopCart);
console.log(cost);
```

```js
var shopCart = [{id: 0,name: 'Womens Shirt',price: 30,size: 'Small'},{id: 1,name: 'childs shirt',price: 12,size: 'Large'}];

function getCost(items){
 return items.reduce((total, {price}) => total + price, 0);
}

let cost = getCost(shopCart);
console.log(cost);
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer same as others really, but within the required parameters.

```js
var shopCart = [
  {
    id: 0,
    name: 'Womens Shirt',
    price: 30,
    size: 'Small'
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'childs shirt',
    price: 12,
    size: 'Large'
  }
]

function getCost(items){
  let total = 0;
  // code below
  total = items.reduce((sum, item) => sum + item.price, total);
  // code above
 return total;
}

let cost = getCost(shopCart);

console.log(cost);
```

Comment: Thanks @oMikey. I had to amend the last 2 lines of the original code as they were not supposed to be included.  

I am not sure I follow why the two prices add to each other.